# What does 'N' represent in an exercise asking to build a simple calendar?

Tags: java

I am trying to answer this question, but I have no idea what the author means by "adding `N*12`".

This is the question:

> Write a complete `Date` class with a constructor `new Date(month, day, year)` that creates a `Date` object with the given month, day and year. Use a hypothetical calendar in which every month has 30 days. A day value outside the range 1 through 30 is to be replaced by 1. **For a negative month number, add N*12 to it and subtract N from the year, to make the month number 1 through 12.** Make the opposite adjustment for month numbers greater than 12.

I have no idea what the variable `N` is supposed to mean here, and I am trying to figure it out. That is all I want help with.

Comment: N=negative month number

Comment: `N` is `N`, a number.  For example, `N=42`.

Comment: it seems that N is user entered value with modulo 12

Comment: Choose N such that the resulting month number will be between 1 and 12.

Comment: Looks like someones homework assignment. Questions regarding homework don't belong on stackoverflow.

Comment: You need to figure out how to calculate `N` - hint: start by writing down some samples on paper (such as what needs `N` to be for `month=-3`, `month=-12`, `month=-15`, `month=3`, `month=15`, etc.) and try to find out the rule behind it

Comment: @M.Deinum Homework questions are OK, as long as OP are not asking to do  their homework for them. It appears that OP wants help in understanding the question, not in writing the code for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`N` says how many years (twelve month intervals) are "built into" the month number. It is a hypothetical number representing one twelfth of the offset to be added to the month or subtracted from it in order to bring the value of the month into its valid range of `1..12`. `N` could be positive, negative, or zero, depending on `M` - the number of the month. In plain words, `N` says how many times we need to add or subtract 12 from `M` in order to bring it into the range of 1..12.

Here are a few examples:

- **`M` is 8** - Since the month is already in the 1..12 range, `N` is 0.
- **`M` is 18** - The month is outside the 1..12 range, so we need to subtract `12` from it in order to bring it into the range. `N` is -1.
- **`M` is -38** - The month is negative. We need to add 12 four times in order to bring it into the range, so `N` is 4.

Answer (score 0):

`N` in this case is a number. It's talking about which number you'll need to add, but not saying which because it'll be different in each circumstance.

Answer (score -1):

N is a user input value(i.e. int month) to your method. From what I see, it can be a negative number too